# SSD frezzes in Windows 10 with 100% active time 0 read 0 write 0 responses time

Tags: windows, ssd, freeze, lag

My new Kingston SSD is freezing a lot on Windows 10. 
I have used more than app to check the SSD and all give me that the SSD is 100% healthy and everything is OK, but I check the Task Manager when the lap freezes it shows that the disk is 100% active 0 read 0 write 0 responses time

What I have tried so far:

- Disabling the Page file for `C:`.
- Running System File Checker /SFC with administrative privileges.
- Disabling several services: Windows Search and Superfetch and prefetch
- Checked SMART status of SSD using Kingston SSD Toolbox.
- Updated Windows using Windows Update.
- reinstalling Windows
- secure erase the SSD
- contact Kingston for help
- checking TRIM is enabled
- check the AHCI driver
- updating all drivers
- scan for virus and malware

Any new ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same problem and done almost everything you described, nothing helped. Finally I've found cause and solution. It was a problem with **Kingston SSD firmware**. Try updating firmware with [Kingston SSD Manager](https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/ssdmanager). Restart after update. Worked for me.

Comment: This has been the best improvement I've had, FYI I had to run the SSD as slave (OS in a different drive) to be able to run this. I've been stressing the drive for testing purposes and not a single freeze.